# Custom vibration pattern in Codename One.

Tags: android, codenameone

I tried modifying the vibration pattern with the build hint android.pushVibratePattern = 1000 and did not have any luck.
Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this to make my custom vibration pattern when the notification arrives:

```
notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000});
```

Where `notificationBuilder` is

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
```

You need to give it a pattern in the form of `long[]`.

For this to work in Codename One the build hin needs to match the arguments to the long array as:

```
android.pushVibratePattern=1000, 1000, 1000
```

Which will translate to the exact same code above. Notice that you need to do this thru the GUI if you edit the `codenameone_settings.properties` file directly you will need to prefix hints with `codename1.arg.`.

Comment: This can be implemented in Codename One?

Comment: Edited the answer to explain how this is achieved in Codename One.

Comment: Thanks @ShaiAlmog. Combined, we've succeeded :D Although you could've probably done it yourself :)

Answer (score 2):

as per Codename One tutorial its written

`android.pushVibratePattern - **Comma delimited long values** to describe the push pattern of vibrate used for the setVibrate native method`

It seems instead of pattern you set only one value 1000

so in your build hint you should try with few values as 1000,500,1000,1500

Good luck.